# Search for mismatched length alternative pattern?

Tags: regular-expression, search

My file consists of the following text

```
one
bone
stone
cuttlebone
minestrone
cornerstone
```

and I want to select all instances of `bone` and `stone`, so I get the following highlighted text:

```
one
BONE
STONE
cuttleBONE
minestrone
cornerSTONE
```

NB: *capitals indicate highlighted text since I can't format in code*.

I have tried the following search patterns, but none of them work

```
/bone|stone
/[st|b]one
/[\(st\)b]one
/[bst]one
/[b(st)]one
```

The problem is `stone` and `bone` are different lengths, and I don't know how to match to two different length options.

**How can I match all instances of `stone` and `bone` in my file?**

Comment: You can try fuzzy search plugins as well ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the `|`:

```
/bone\|stone
```

If you want to reuse the `one` part, you can do:

```
/\(b\|st\)one
```

This create a sub expression `b\|st` and add `one` to it.

As DJ McMayhem suggested, you can use the `\v` "verymagic" flag:

```
/\v(b|st)one
```

Comment: Or `/\v(b|st)one`

Answer (score 5):

Nobe4's answer is spot-on. Here's an alternative.

[vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish). This plugin works fantastic for searching and/or replacing simple variants on a word. For example, let's say you want to turn 'child' to 'adult', while also getting 'children' to 'adults', and all case-variants. You can do that with:

```
:Subvert/child{,ren}/adult{,s}/g
```

In your case, you can do a subvert search with:

```
:Subvert /{st,b}one
```